# Are there any commerical or open source IDEs that have built-in support for compiling ILASM files?

Tags: ide, ilasm

Are there any IDEs out there apart (from Visual Studio) that will let you build IL assembler files right out of the IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) supports building .NET languages using the Mono compiler, and is available on Linux, Mac OS, and Windows.  According to the [package description](http://linuxappfinder.com/package/monodevelop), many .NET languages are supported, including ILasm:

> MonoDevelop is a GNOME IDE primarily designed for C# and other CLI (.NET) languages.
>
> It supports the following languages: C, C++, C# (1.0, 2.0 and 3.0), Vala, Boo, Java, Nemerle, ILasm, ASP.NET and VB.NET.
>
> Features: Debugger Integration (Mono Debugger and GNU Debugger), Class Browser, Assembly Browser, Built-in Help, Monodoc Integration, Code Completion (also known as IntelliSense), Code Folding, Color Schemes, Code Refactoring, On-the-fly error underlining, XML Editing, Embedded HTML viewer, Gettext support, GTK# Designer, MSBuild project support and Makefile Generation.

Comment: I said building IL assembler, not C# or VB.NET :)

Comment: @plaureano: ilasm is supported as well, I've updated my answer with the description for the Linux package.  I haven't used MonoDevelop for building outside of C# files, so I'm not sure exactly what the process for ilasm is.